# Compile error (Illegal unit) only with TeXlive 2015

Tags: texlive, documentclass-writing

I've written my own class (some kind of student research project).

https://github.com/faltfe/iodhbwm

As far as I tested it with TeXlive 2017 and MiKTeX (up-to-date) it is working fine. Now a colleague tried to compile with TeXlive 2015 and run into an error. I could reproduce the same error by installing TeXlive 2015 `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` under Ubuntu LTS 16.04.

I created the following MWE

```
\documentclass{iodhbwm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

and got the error

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   f
l.263 \definecolor{DHBW-blue}{HTML}{026f93}
```

My problem is why do I get this error with TeXlive 2015 and not with TeXlive 2017 or with MiKTeX? How can I start debugging at this point?

You can find the color definition inside https://github.com/faltfe/iodhbwm/blob/master/iodhbwm.cls at line 263.

Comment: Is that your own class file, or did someone give it to you?  Why are you using it and not something more standard?

Comment: This is my own class file. I use this only for specific reports with given standards.

Comment: Why not try making a version of your class which is minimal and recreates the error (with TL15)?

Comment: if you get an error in an old release but not in a newer one, that is surely the expected behaviour, bugs get fixed.

Comment: @DaiBowen Somethings it can be so simply :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So this means that it might be an old bug inside TL15 or does this mean that packages aren't updated to the latest avaiable versions?

Comment: if you are using texlive 2015 none of the packages are likely to be the latest versions, there will be no package updates to texlive 2015 since the texlive 2016 testing started which would have been march 2016 most likely. I don't have tl2015 but there is no error with texlive 2016 and texlive 2018

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your explanation and thanks for testing with TL16. Then I can only advice my colleagues to use at least TL16.

Comment: It’s a bug of xcolor described elsewhere on the site and fixed in a version of TeX Live later than 2015.

Comment: presumably it was a bug in the HTML code so you could specify those colors in RGB instead. HTML}{026f93} is RGB{"02,"6F."93}

Comment: You can use the patch I added in the suggested duplicate.